# Fifty two week high and low

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a records table with the following data. We need to fill fifty-two week(or 365 days)high and low amounts in ft_high and ft_low columns? How can we accomplish this in MySQL?

*Fifty-two-week data including the same date.*

```
id  user_id date    amount  ft_high ft_low
10  21  2020-10-11  1500    1800    950
11  22  2020-10-12  1950    2410    1738
12  21  2020-10-15  1150    1800    1500
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
99  21  2020-11-15  1950    1950    950
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
selet t.*,
      min(amount) over (partition by user_id order by date range between interval 52 week preceding and current row) as ft_low,
      max(amount) over (partition by user_id order by date range between interval 52 week preceding and current row) as ft_high,
from t;
```

Comment: Didn't work:
#4021 - Numeric datatype is required for RANGE-type frame
@Gordon

Comment: @KrishnaGuragai . . . Most emphatically not true.  MySQL supports interval on window frames:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html.  And your question is tagged MySQL.